# Web API returning UTF-16

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a simple test api

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{

 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Post([FromBody] FulfillmentRequst data)
    {
       var obj = new DummyObject();
       Ok(obj)
    }
}
```

The problem can be seen in the logs the post request comes in as UTF-8 but the response is going out at UTF-16.

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://371395ef.ngrok.io/api/values application/json; **charset=UTF-8** 3401
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
>         Route matched with {action = "Post", controller = "Values"}. Executing action WebApplicationAPI.Controllers.ValuesController.Post (WebApplicationAPI)
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
>         Executing action method 
> WebApplicationAPI.Controllers.ValuesController.Post (WebApplicationAPI) with arguments (ActionsOnGoogle.Core.v2.Request.FulfillmentRequst) - Validation state: Valid
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>         Executed action method WebApplicationAPI.Controllers.ValuesController.Post (WebApplicationAPI), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult in 8.796ms.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
>         Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'ActionsOnGoogle.Core.v2.Response.SimpleResponseResponse'.
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>         Executed action WebApplicationAPI.Controllers.ValuesController.Post (WebApplicationAPI) in 267.2988ms
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 508.7373ms 200 application/json; **charset=utf-16**

This is a brand new .net core web api.  I haven't changed anything in the settings.   How do I force it to return utf-8 when returning a json response from the API.

The main issue is the server on the other reading from the web hook apparently cant handle the utf-16 its parsing it as garbage.

> Expect message object but got: \"笀∀瀀愀礀氀漀愀搀∀㨀笀∀最漀漀最氀攀∀㨀笀∀攀砀瀀攀挀琀唀猀攀爀刀攀猀瀀漀渀猀攀∀㨀琀爀甀攀Ⰰ∀爀椀挀栀刀攀猀瀀漀渀猀攀∀㨀笀∀椀琀攀洀猀∀㨀嬀笀∀猀椀洀瀀氀攀刀攀猀瀀漀渀猀攀∀㨀笀∀琀攀砀琀吀漀匀瀀攀攀挀栀∀㨀∀圀伀刀䬀 䐀䄀䴀䤀吀∀紀紀崀紀紀紀紀\"."

Comment: That's odd. .NET Core specifically uses UTF-8 for cross-platform compatibility. The default for the response encoding should be UTF-8, not UTF-16. Are you sure you, another developer, or some package you're using hasn't customized things?

Comment: nope its a pure .net core 2.1 web api.   I have never seen it send utf-16 before either I have been bashing my head on this all afternoon

Comment: I am having this same problem. Using .net core 2.1, AWS api gateway, AWS lambda, etc... Did you get to fix this issue?

Comment: I also have the same problem here. What was the problem and did you fix it?

Comment: It seems this is very specific. I am having the same issue and I think should be resolved in next .net core update.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can force the response using the Charset property. Something like that:

```
public class CharsetAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] += ";charset=utf-8";
        }
}
```

Comment: I left work after posting this I will give it a try in the morning.  Thanks